# Use Google Drive Directory as Apache Virtual host

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, google-drive-api

I am trying to set up an Apache 2.4 server with my google drive folder.
I already did it with Dropbox and it's working fine, but with google drive, Apache can't find the directory.

After some research, I have discovered that the real path of google drive folder is in

> C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db

but it's all compiled. Is there a way to get the path ?

I have already tried with this KiXtart script :

> http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=204938

...which is not working anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive hosting changes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302170/google-drive-hosting-changes-in-url)

Answer (score 14):

It is a permissions issue. Right click 'Google Drive' Folder -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Advanced -> Change Permissions... -> Check 'Include inheritable permissions from parent folder'.

Comment: Might be worth noting, right clicking on a shortcut to your Google Drive folder doesn't work... Right click on the actual google Drive folder, probably in C:\Users\USERNAME

Comment: Do you know how to do it on windows 10. Can't seem to find the option

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm still getting 403, even after restarting the server.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a permissions issue. Change the permissions of the Google Drive folder to inherit all the permissions of the parent folder, then you're good to go.

Comment: It's a bit tight that this doesn't get as many upvotes as the answer by user1997944 even though it is the right answer and 4 days earlier.

Comment: @Caltor, likely because the other answer included the path to the setting

Answer (score 2):

You can map the google drive folder to a drive, then install the wmap/virtual host to this path:

```
subst x: "C:\{pathname}\{foldername}"
```

Edit: added quotes encase of space in {foldername} (e.g. /Google Drive/)