# Wamp is stuck on "Server Offline" after directory change

Tags: wamp, wampserver, httpd.conf

I wanted to change the folder from which Wamp reads its files, from the `www` folder inside the wamp folder to somewhere else.

I've tried to change the `httpd.conf` file and replace each occurrence of the original `www` folder with my new folder. The problem is that after I do that and run Wamp, it is stuck on an orange icon with the message "Server Offline" and doesn't seem to really start. When I change the `httpd.conf` file back to what it was Wamp manages to run successfully.

What am I doing wrong? How can I change the `www` folder and still have a working Wamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was because I tried to change my Wamp directory to something inside Google Drive. This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444634/458152

Answer (score 1):

It is best to create `Virtual Hosts` for this purpose. Leave wamps stuff where it is and create a `Virtual Hosts` for each of your projects.

**HowTo: Create Virtual Hosts in WAMPServer**

*BEFORE DOING ANY OF THIS PLEASE ENSURE APACHE AND MYSQL ARE WORKING PROPERLY FIRST!!!*

Create a new folder outside the wamp directory structure. This folder can be on any disk drive visible to the PC running wamp. So if you installed WAMP on C:\ this could be on D:\ or E:\ etc

```
C:\websites
```

Create a subfolder in c:\websites for each site you want to create.
   eg:

```
C:\websites\site1
C:\websites\site2
```

Edit the file C:\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf where x,y and z are the version numbers of apache that you actually have installed.

NOTE: If you are switching between 2 or more versions of apache this will have to be done to all your versions of apache in turn.

SUGGESTION: I like to use the format sitename.dev to make it obvious to me that I am dealing with my localhost development copy of a site, you may prefer another notation, thats ok, the word dev has no actual defined meaning in this case, its just my way of naming my development versions of a live site.

Remove the lines that already exists in this file. They are just examples.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

## must be first so the the wamp menu page loads when you use just localhost as the domain name
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/site1"
    ServerName site1.dev
    ServerAlias www.site1.dev
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "C:/websites/www/site1">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Add as many  as you require so each of your sites have one, changing the DocumentRoot, ServerName and any other of the parameters as appropriate.
This also allows you to make SITE SPECIFIC changes to the configuration.

NOTE: This will make the wamp manager "Put Online" function no longer have any effect on these new vhost'ed sites as the security for each one is now part of the vhost definition, so leave WAMP, OFFLINE. If you want to put one or more sites online you will have to change the Allow commands MANUALLY in the httpd-vhosts.conf file.

To check your subnet do the following:
Launch a command window, and run

```
ipconfig
```

Look for the line "Default Gateway" in the output and use the third number in your Allow commands.

Edit your httpd.conf file and search for these lines, they are near the bottom of the file.

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Remove the '#' comment character on this line to Include your newly changed vhosts, this will cause apache to register their existance.

While still editing your httpd.conf file search for this section of it

```
onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

**DO NOT CHANGE THESE LINES!**

Add the following after the <\Directory> tag to secure your new C:\websites folder.

```
<Directory "C:/websites/">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

This is to set security on your new directory structure so that access to these new sites is only allowed from 127.0.0.1 (localhost) unless amended from within a specific VHOST.
You can add to this as your requirements change. For example if you want anyone on your subnet to be allowed access to your site(s) you can add `Allow from 192.168.0' to this list assuming you are on subnet 192.168.0, check using 'ipconfig'.

Now in order for your browser to know how to get to these new domain names i.e. site1.dev and site2.dev, we need to tell windows what IP address they are located on. There is a file called HOSTS that is a hangover from the days before Domain Name Servers (DNS) were invented. It is a way of giving nice easy rememberable names to IP address's, which of course is what DNS Servers do for us all now.

Edit your HOSTS file, this can be found in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc , the file does not have an extension. Windows protects this file so you must be an Administrator to be allowed to save changes to this file.

If you are using VISTA or Windows7/8 you may think you are an Administrator BUT YOU ARE NOT!!!!
So to edit this file you must launch your editor, or Notepad in a specific way to gain Administrator rights. To do this find your editors icon and launch it using the following key strokes:
Shift + Right Click over its icon, this will display a menu, click the item "Run as Administrator", and click "Allow" on the challenge dialog that will appear.

Now you are ready to edit the hosts file so navigate your editor to c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Add the following lines to this file

```
127.0.0.1   site1.dev
127.0.0.1   site2.dev
```

### NOTE: You will need to add one line in this file for each of your new virtual hosts.

In order for Apache to pick up these changes you must bounce ( stop and restart ) apache. 
Do this by: Wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Restart Service

You should now be able to use the address site1.dev in your browser to get to your new sites. Copy your sites code into the "C:/websites/xxxx" folder if you already have a site coded or, place a quick and simple index.php file into the "c:\websites\xxxx" folder to proove it all works.

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SITE1</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
     echo '<div style="background-color:red;color;white;text-align:center;font-size:18px">HELLO FROM Site1</div>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

### TROUBLE SHOOTING:

If you have used the new domain name ( site1.dev ) and it has not found the site.
a. Check the changes to the hosts file.
b. Restart the "DNS Service" that runs in windows. This caches all doman names that you use in a browser so that the browser does not have to query a DNS Server each time you re-use a domain name. This may have cached your failed attempt but a restart is easy and should solve the problem and is quicker that re-booting windows, which should also work.
To do this launch a command window as an Administrator ( Shift + Left Click over the command window icon ) and run these 2 commands.

```
net stop "DNS Client"
net start "DNS Client"
```

#### Note: The quotes are required as there is a space in the services name.