# wamp alias error, spaces in the directory name

Tags: apache, wamp

I have two alias, one works and one not. I think the problem with the wrong one is that has spaces in the directory name because is the only difference.

This works:

```
Alias /test/ "c:/test/noteboardapp/" 

<Directory "c:/test/noteboardapp/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
     Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This doesn't work:

```
Alias /noteboard/ "c:/Documents\ and\ Settings/odedios/Mis\ documentos/Google\ Drive/Trabajo/www/noteboardapp/"

<Directory "c:/Documents\ and\ Settings/odedios/Mis\ documentos/Google\ Drive/Trabajo/www/noteboardapp/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
      Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have the error: "You don't have permission to access /noteboard/ on this server."

I've scaped the spaces with "\" If I don't do the server doesn't run.

What is wrong?

Thank you!

Oscar.

**EDITED**:  I've found the solution here [Use Google Drive Directory as Apache Virtual host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122267/use-google-drive-directory-as-apache-virtual-host)

The problem was that I was using a google drive folder and I have to change the permissions to access to this folder:

Right click 'Google Drive' Folder -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Advanced -> Change Permissions... -> Check 'Include inheritable permissions from parent folder'.

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
Alias /noteboard/ "c:/Documents\ and\ Settings/odedios/Mis\ documentos/Google\ Drive/Trabajo/www/noteboardapp/"
```

You're telling Apache to find this directory:

```
C:\Documents\ and\ Settings\odedios\Mis\ documentos\Google\ Drive\Trabajo\www\noteboardapp\
```

Just remove all those bogus backslash characters.

**Edit:** White space is not the only difference between your two settings. The second alias points to a user profile, which is likely to be protected so only user *odedios* can read it.

Comment: Alvaro, without the backslashes the server shutdown and doesn't work. The backslashes is to scape the space characters, is it wrong?

Comment: I'm not aware of any language where whitespace needs to be escaped inside quoted strings. What does "server shutdown and doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I've found in some web the backslash solution for the spaces, but I don't remember where. I am using windows but apache uses the unix file system and I think unix doesn't accept spaces in the file names (I'm not sure about this). The server doesn't start with this spaces without scape, localhost doesn't work.

Comment: @Oscardrbcn Right, "doesn't start" suggests you aren't aware of log files. Please browse to the folder where Apache is installed. You'll have a folder there called "logs". You'll find the exact reason for the error right there. You can also use Apache's "Test Configuration" icon in the Windows Start menu. Also, see my edit.

Comment: yes I know the log files but I don't understand anything about this: Server built: May 13 2012 13:32:42
Created child process 1176
Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Child 1176: Child process is running
Child 1176: Acquired the start mutex.
Child 1176: Starting 64 worker threads.
Child 1176: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
Child 1176: Released the start mutex
Child 1176: All worker threads have exited.
Child 1176: Child process is exiting
Child process exited successfully.

Comment: Regarding your editing, yes it could be something about it. I'm the user odedios but I've tried the another "test" alias and I've changed the folder name for one with spaces, and I didn't have problems, it works (without backslashes etc).

Comment: I've found the solution, the problem was that I was using a google drive folder, I've edited the question with the solution. !Gracias por tu ayuda!.