# Moving Apache aliased directory into google drive will give me access forbidden errors

Tags: windows, apache, permissions

I'm moving my local development server on Google drive so i can share it amongst my computers but since i did that i can't access my files through a browser anymore, i have an "Access Forbidden" error. On the Apache error logs i have this:

> [authz_core:error] [pid 11144:tid 1268] [client 127.0.0.1:59641] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Users/Val/Google Drive/workspaces

I haven't changed anything in my apache configuration, except for the directory

```
Alias /phpprojects "C:\Users\Val\Google Drive\workspaces\workspace-php"
<Directory "C:\Users\Val\Google Drive\workspaces\workspace-php">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The directory was C:\Users\Val\workspaces\workspace-php before changing it

I have already tried what's suggested here http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,110159,110159 (giving permissions to SYSTEM, and then tried even "Everyone") and i have tried what's suggested here [Use Google Drive Directory as Apache Virtual host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122267/use-google-drive-directory-as-apache-virtual-host) (though i'm on Windows 8 so the ui is slightly different, i have activated "allow inheritance"), none of these worked.

What else can be tried to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit embarassing at this point but i have realized that the problem was that i had set a wrong path.
The "Access Forbidden" errors and the fact I found evidence about access forbidden errors when using google drive lead me into thinking that it was a permission issue rather than a path issue so i didn't even check it, until now.